# curl not returning anything rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ruby-on-rails-5

I just started a brand new Rails 5 beta 4 project and scaffolded a tables resource. And i am trying to work with curl in order to test my api endpoints but it does not work for some reason.

so i have access to url `http://localhost:3000/tables`

now when i type `curl http://localhost:3000/tables`

For some reason it returns nothing, not even an empty array [] like i was expecting, and i can see no request being made in rails server, am i missing something?

EDIT:

when i access `localhost:3000` in browser it does not show anything but in browser console it says

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

now when i try to access it via `127.0.0.1:3000` it works. even curl works without the localhost part.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but can you restart your server and make sure it's running on port 3000? You may be pulling up a cache in your  browser.

Comment: @AnthonyE hmm thats weird but when i access `localhost:3000` it does not show anything but in browser console it says  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`, now when i try to access it  via `127.0.0.1:3000` it works. even curl works without the localhost part.

Comment: Do you have a line like this: `127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0` in your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: ah nope its `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: That should be fine too

Comment: you should have a configuration problem on your host.

The call to curl only displays the contents of the response (not their headers), so if you have a 500 error in your browser but get a blank page, curl should not show anything

Comment: What's says *the rails console* e.g. rails server log? 500 (Internal Server Error) means error in the server code.

Comment: What ruby web server are you ussing?

Comment: Hmm i have restarted my computer and the error went away i can now access both localhost in browser and curl. thats really weird and if i do not find the cause of it, possibly i will happen again. @felipecamposclarke i am using puma comes with rails 5.

Comment: I spend something similar with Puma, with the difference that I could access `localhost` but not directly to `127.0.0.1`. - https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782

Answer (score 0):

The rails 5 setup also uses spring to speed things up - it will have a worker in the background ready to get going. The puma setup is also a little strange in that by default it will only accept connections on localhost and not 127.0.0.1 but you can work around this by starting rails with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`. I say strange, but I dare say there is some rationale behind it ;-). To see if there are any stuck spring processes still running you can run `ps aux | grep spring` and then kill it `kill -9 <process id>`